# Which method is best for automatically stop mediaplayer after 10 seconds?

Tags: android, countdowntimer, android-handler

I am using Android 6.0 and play an default music. The music must automatically stop after playing 10 seconds. This is my function

```
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
public void playSound(){
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    try {
        if (mp != null &&  mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp=null;
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        mp.start();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mp.stop();
            }
        }, 10000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
     @Override
public void onDestroy() {
      if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
     }
}
```

It worked well but when I call the `playSound()` twice time within 10 seconds, then stopping time (10seconds) runs in shorter time. Hence, I think the Handler is not good in my case. Do you think timer is better? Or do I need to stop the Handler when I call the `playSound` function. Thanks all

Instead of using Handler, I am using timer as

```
if(mCountDownTimer_Playing!=null){
                mCountDownTimer_Playing.cancel();
                mCountDownTimer_Playing=null;
            }
            mCountDownTimer_Playing = new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mpCalling.stop();
                }
            };
            mCountDownTimer_Playing.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TimerTask instead,

```
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
Timer timer = null;
public void playSound() {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer=null;}
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        mp.start();
        timer= new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mp.stop();
            }
        }, 10000);
}
```